# Is it possible to set "isobstacle" only for agents in the Storage?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to simulate a logistic center, where pallets are moved. I want the transporters from my fleet to move freely through the whole center and drive over storages, because the storages are just markings on the ground in reality. So I unchecked the isobstacle-Checkbox in the Storage properties. But now the transporters also drive over my pallets, if they are in the Storage.
I already tried to put a rectangular wall under my pallet, but it didn't work. I guess the pallets become part of the storage, when they are stored.
Is it possible to only set the pallets in my storage as obstacle, but not the storage itself?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can small single pallet, pallet racks under the storage locations of each pallet and then dynamically change them to obstacles using `setObstacle(isObstacle)` if you place a pallet in that location.

If they make the animation look weird you can set their visibility to false.

If you have lots of places to place pallet you can also create these dummy pallet racks programmatically using

```
palletRack = new PalletRack(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, true, 130.0, 230.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 50.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_SINGLE_AISLE_RIGHT, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
            0.0, 40.0, 20.0, 1, 1, 1, lavender, dodgerBlue, 2 );
```

Check the help for more details on the constructor

Since this can be cumbersome to handle I can suggest the following - have not tested it but it should work - create your dummy pallete rack everytime you store a pallet

[image]

You might need to add it to the presentation using `presentation.add(palletRack)`
and remove it again.

Else what I would do is simply create a map of all the possible pallet locations and create a dummy pallet for each location and then when you store the pallet the pallete checks it location and simply looks up the correct dummy pallet from the collection and call `setObstacle(true)`. When you remove it from the palette rack you set it to false...

If you want to use free moving transported the only way to have obstacles being switched on or off is with the obstacle characteristic AnyLogic created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am constructing a big logistic center, so the dummy palletracks are difficult to realize, because there are so many pallets and I have to control one pallet rack for each pallet. So there would be no advantage in using storages anymore. I think about creating own storage agents which have the functions that I need. But that would be a lot more of work...

Comment: See my updated answer - I hope it helps. It is definitely possible... Contact me privately if you need more help

Comment: That was a great idea, thank you. The palletRack is created at the position, but unfortunatly the transporters seem to move underneath it although everthing is in z=0.0. It seems like the PalletRacks are just visible but not obstacles, although isobstacle is set true...
Probably I have to create those palletRacks in advance like you suggested. The Problem is that there are more than 150 storages with 32 positions. So I would prefer an automated solution :)

Comment: Maybe send your model to AnyLogic support for assistance...

Comment: The support answered that the paletts are part of the storage, when "isobstacle" is chosen. They are working on a floor storage support, but the release is unknown.